# Name mismatch in my degree, marksheets and employer reference for ACS skill assesment

Tags: australia, skilled-migration, pr

I am applying for skill assessment via ACS (Australian Computer Society) and have some confusion regarding the names which are mentioned on my degree, marksheets and employer reference letters.

1) The names mentioned on my college marksheets for my bachelor's degree are Ganjoo Suvin

2) The names mentioned on my university marksheets for my bachelor's degree are Ganjoo Suvin Sohan Lal Rajni (Surname First name Fathers's name and Mother's name)

3) The names mentioned on my Degree is (Ganjoo Suvin Sohan Lal Rajni)

4) The names mentioned on my employer reference is Suvin Ganjoo

Please note, that in India, marksheets for the first year (two semesters) and last year (two semesters) are issued directly by University and, hence, points 1 and 2.

Are these variations going to create a problem in the skill assessment and the results?

Comment: You might contact ACS and ask if a notarized letter that lists all name variations as being "you" would be acceptable. Or if this is a problem at all. In the US, that's sometimes done for mortgages/contracts. You list all possible variants of your "name." I've only ever had one name, but there was a credit reference with my first and last name switched somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok.

I have my name misspelled (a typo) on one of my references and IELTS exam and they got accepted by ASC, so you should be fine...

They expect to get references sometimes with full name sometimes not....